# How to get the Label Name with the next div value using Selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Consider the below snippet

```
<div class="contentInput medium wrapText">
<label class="ng-binding">Number1</label>
<div title="10000" class="readOnlyInput clearB wrapText  text-left ng-binding">10000</div>
</div>
<div class="contentInput medium wrapText">
<label class="ng-binding">Number2</label>
<div title="10050" class="readOnlyInput clearB wrapText  text-left ng-binding">10050</div>
</div>
<div class="contentInput medium wrapText">
<label class="ng-binding">Number2</label>
<div class="readOnlyInput clearB wrapText  text-left ng-binding">....</div>
</div>
```

Here are my problems:

1. How can I get the label with the next div value? For example, I need to get Number1 value as 10000,Number2 value as 10050 and Number 3 value as BLANK.
2. If I give the Label as Input, then it's value should be returned from the next div of that label?
   For Example, if the number 1 is given as Input, then 10000 value should be returned

Comment: Share your code and website. Difficult to address in this way. :-)

Comment: So, you looking for xpath, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be very simple as below:

`String labelText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[label = 'Number1']/div")).getText();`

You may not even need a method because it is just one line. If you want `div` value for other label, say, `Number2`, just replace the value.

The way you use `xpath` that makes it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code:

```
public string getLabelValue(String labelText)
{
   List <WebElement> outerDiv= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='contentInput medium wrapText']"));
    for (WebElement div: outerDiv) {
      if(div.findElements(By.tagName("label").getText().equals(labelText))){
            return div.findElements(By.tagName("div").getText();
      }
    }
   return "Label Not Found".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try it like below

```
// taking under consideration that we have same number of label 
// tag with its corresponding div tag

// Take label tag and div tag in list 
List<WebElement> myLabels = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ng-binding"));
List<WebElement> myDivs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".readOnlyInput.clearB.wrapText.text-left.ng-binding"));
String UserInputLabelValue = "Number2";
// now size of myLabels = myDivs hence
for(int i=0;i<myLabels.size();i++){
    if(myLabels.get(i).getText().equals(UserInputLabelValue)){
    System.out.println("Div value is against " + UserInputLabelValue + " is : " + myDivs.get(i).getText());
            }
        }
```